# Объявление типа переменной передаваемой в функцию

Tags: php

Объявил функцию с переменной `int`, передаю `int`. Вываливается ошибка:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to myTest() must be an instance of int, integer given

Почему?

```
myTest(intval(3));
    function myTest(int $val){
}
```

Comment: type hinting только для объектов, а не для скалярных типов, т.е. php ждет, что вы объект int (а не тип int) передадите. Про это прямо в документации [написано](http://php.net/language.oop5.typehinting): `Контроль типа не может быть использован со скалярными типами, такими как int или string. Ресурсы и Трейты также недопустимы.`

Comment: От оно что ) Спасибо!

Comment: Ну или на php7 обновитесь, да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В php5.* [type hinting](http://php.net/language.oop5.typehinting) вы можете в обяъвлении функции проверять только на массив или определенный класс, скалярные типы ввели только в php7.* – http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php